# How are my bytes in C stored?

Tags: c, memory, storage

First, I'm a student still. So I am not very experienced.

I'm working with a piece of bluetooth hardware and I am using its protocol to send it commands. The protocol requires packets to be sent with LSB first for each packet field.

I was getting error packets back to me indicating my CRC values were wrong so I did some investigating. I found the problem, but I became confused in the process.

Here is Some GDB output and other information elucidating my confusion.

I'm sending a packet that should look like this:

```
|Start Flag| Packet Num | Command | Payload |    CRC    | End Flag|
    0xfc        0x1       0x0 0x8   0x0 0x5   0x59 0x42    0xfd
```

Here is some GDB output:

```
print /x reqId_ep
$1 = {start_flag = 0xfc, data = {packet_num = 0x1, command = {0x0, 0x8}, payload = {
  0x0, 0x5}}, crc = 0x5942, end_flag = 0xfd}
```

reqId_ep is the variable name of the packet I'm sending. It looks all good there, but I am receiving the CRC error codes from it so something must be wrong.

Here I examine 9 bytes in hex starting from the address of my packet to send:

```
x/9bx 0x7fffffffdee0
0xfc    0x01    0x00    0x08    0x00    0x05    0x42    0x59    0xfd
```

And here the problem becomes apparent. The CRC is not LSB first. (0x42 0x59)

To fix my problem I removed the htons() that I set my CRC value equal with.

And here is the same output above without htons():

```
p/x reqId_ep

$1 = {start_flag = 0xfc, data = {packet_num = 0x1, command = {0x0, 0x8}, payload = {
  0x0, 0x5}}, crc = 0x4259, end_flag = 0xfd}
```

Here the CRC value is not LSB.

But then:

```
x/9bx 0x7fffffffdee0
0xfc    0x01    0x00    0x08    0x00    0x05    0x59    0x42    0xfd
```

Here the CRC value is LSB first.

So apparently the storing of C is LSB first? Can someone please cast a light of knowledge upon me for this situation? Thank you kindly.

Comment: It depends on the processor you're running.  Numeric values larger than one byte can be stored either "big-endian" or "little-endian".  (Google the terms and study up.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with Endianness in computing:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_operating_systems_on_architectures

For example, the value 4660 (base-ten) is 0x1234 in hex. On a Big Endian system, it would be stored in memory as `1234` while on a Little Endian system it would be stored as `3412`

If you want to avoid this sort of issue in the future, it might just be easiest to create a large array or struct of unsigned char, and store individual values in it.

eg:

```
|Start Flag| Packet Num | Command | Payload |    CRC    | End Flag|
    0xfc        0x1       0x0 0x8   0x0 0x5   0x59 0x42    0xfd

typedef struct packet {
  unsigned char startFlag;
  unsigned char packetNum;
  unsigned char commandMSB;
  unsigned char commandLSB;
  unsigned char payloadMSB;
  unsigned char payloadLSB;
  unsigned char crcMSB;
  unsigned char crcLSB;
  unsigned char endFlag;
} packet_t;
```

You could then create a function that you compile differently based on the type of system you are building for using preprocessor macros.

eg:

```
/* Uncomment the line below if you are using a little endian system;
/* otherwise, leave it commented
 */
//#define LITTLE_ENDIAN_SYSTEM

// Function protocol
void writeCommand(int cmd);


//Function definition
void writeCommand(int cmd, packet_t* pkt)
{
  if(!pkt)
  {
     printf("Error, invalid pointer!");
     return;
  }

  #if LITTLE_ENDIAN_SYSTEM
    pkt->commandMSB = (cmd && 0xFF00) >> 8;
    pkt->commandLSB = (cmd && 0x00FF);
  # else  //  Big Endian system
    pkt->commandMSB = (cmd && 0x00FF);
    pkt->commandLSB = (cmd && 0xFF00) >> 8;
  #endif

  // Done
}

int main void() 
{
  packet_t myPacket = {0};  //Initialize so it is zeroed out
  writeCommand(0x1234,&myPacket);


  return 0;
}
```

One final note: avoid sending structs as a stream of data, send it's individual elements one-at-a-time instead! ie: don't assume that the struct is stored internally in this case like a giant array of unsigned characters. There are things that the compiler and system put in place like packing and allignment, and the struct could actually be larger than `9 x sizeof(unsigned char)`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a very detailed illumination of my confusion followed with a great answer to my next logical question.

Comment: Not a problem. Best of luck in your studies!

Answer (score 1):

This is architecture dependent based on which processor you're targeting. There are what is known as "Big Endian" systems, which store the most significant byte of a word first, and "Little Endian" systems that store the least significant byte first. It looks like you're looking at a Little Endian system there.